# SQL 2008 on windows 2008 R2 not working when TLS 1.0 and 1.1 is disabled

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with SQL 2008 on windows 2008 R2 when TLS 1.0 and 1.1 is disabled. After I disabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 I cannot start SQL Service.

[image]

and event viewer shows these errors :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i searched every where but i could not find any solution. can any one suggest anything? thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the appropriate update for the product:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

SQL Server 2008 SP4 10.0.6547.0 TLS 1.2 Update
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/hotfix/kbhotfix?kbnum=3144113&kbln=en-us

Comment: thank you so much. i have upgrade my SQL server to service pack 4 and then with the hotfix everything worked perfectly